# Resorting items with a single database update

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Let's say you're reordering items in your queue on Netflix. For every example I've seen of this sort of thing, when you move the last item to the top, it updates every record in the database, one at a time.

```
1. One Fine Day              ==> change sort order from 1 to 2
2. Two and a Half Men        ==> change sort order from 2 to 3
3. Three Kings (move to top) ==> change sort order from 3 to 1
```

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe one that only requires one database update each time you reorder in item? Consider this:

```
1. One Fine Day              ==> do nothing (sort order stays at 1)
2. Two and a Half Men        ==> do nothing (sort order stays at 2)
3. Three Kings (move to top) ==> change sort order from 3 to 0
```

Moving an item between two other items would split the difference between the sort orders:

```
1. One Fine Day              ==> do nothing (sort order stays at 1)
2. Two and a Half Men        ==> do nothing (sort order stays at 2)
3. Three Kings (move to mid) ==> change sort order from 3 to 2.5
```

To go one step further, we can use a larger character set than just digits, maybe going to base64 and sorting alphabetically, which would give you near unlimited resorting before having to reorder all the items to keep working space between items.

**Anyways, what is the smartest way to hit your DB when resorting?**

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario, as I understood it, is the following:

1. For the sake of simplicity, let's imagine that we have 3 tables `Movies`, `Users` and `UserPreferenes` (the last one, with the columns `UserId`, `MovieId` and `Ordinal`).
2. Each time an user changes his preference over the sorting of his favorite movies, we should update the `UserPreferences` table.
3. But that usually requires updating the `Ordinal` column **for at least 2 records** (with some exceptions, but I'm not narrowing the overall logic to those cases)
4. So, the question would be: how can we avoid multiple updates and update only one record instead?

If the above is correct, a workaround solution would be [**denormalization**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization). There is no general solution and with the risk of caveats on each direction you would choose, there are a couple of alternatives that I suggest you should consider:

1. To have not three, but only two columns in the `UserPreferences`, by keeping the `UserId` column and storing a sequence of the user's favorite movies ids in another column, `OrderedMovieIds`.
2. To convert the `Ordinal` column into a finite number of columns which would indicate the preferences of the user: `Ordinal1`, `Ordinal2`, ... `OrdinalN` (of course this is limited by the table maximum number of columns).